# Charles breaks when run through a symlink

Tags: symbolic-link

Charles proxy is installed right now in `/opt/charles`. Running `/opt/charles/bin/charles` starts Charles successfully. Now I want to add it to my PATH. `ln -s /opt/charles/bin/charles /usr/local/bin/charles` runs successfully and creates a soft link in my `/usr/local/bin` directory. However, when I run charles via `/usr/local/bin/charles` I get the error message:

> Charles lib directory not found. Looking in /usr/lib/charles-proxy.

Why does Charles start successfully when run directly but not when run through the symlink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of presence of relative path  in you `charles` file .

```
    # Find Charles lib directory
      if [ -z "$CHARLES_LIB"]; then
         CHARLES_LIB=`dirname $0`/../lib              # <==HERE..
         if [ ! -f "$CHARLES_LIB/charles.jar" ]; then
              CHARLES_LIB="/usr/lib/charles-proxy"
         fi
  fi
```

Change it into absolute path so that it can refer to it's own  lib directory

```
  # Find Charles lib directory
   if [ -z "$CHARLES_LIB"]; then
      CHARLES_LIB=`dirname $0`/../lib
      if [ ! -f "$CHARLES_LIB/charles.jar" ]; then
         CHARLES_LIB="/opt/charles/lib"              #<== EDIT
     fi
fi
```

It should work.